# can Rich Internet Application run with whole browser uninstalled?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, rich-internet-application

I know that rich internet applications can be run out of browser, but if I uninstall browser, can they still run? I am not sure, which technology of
[Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) be used? (It will run out of chrome). If I uninstall chrome, can it still run?

Comment: You couldn't run it without browser.

Comment: @Lesha Ogonkov which technology Postman used? Rich Internet Application?

Comment: It's required browser to run. In theory, if you have sources of that app, you probably could compile it to make it run as desktop app, like Atom https://atom.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can build RIA with other tools, for example, Adobe AIR. And then it can be run as a standalone application without the browser.